# jQuery Animation Issue On Mouseenter

Tags: jquery, animation, rel

So I've stumbled my way through coding this little section of a site, but it's a little buggy. I know just enough jquery to be dangerous, but I'm hoping some one could help me make this better and more efficient.

Here's what I think could improve this but I have no idea how to accomplish these:

1. After rolling over the first city, when moving to the next, it
   shouldn't bring back all the other markers and then re-hide them. It
   should just hide the marker you were on and then show the one you're
   currently over, but mouseout and a delay it brings back all the markers.
2. Currently if you go from one rollover to the next in a somewhat
   rapid pace, the animation seems to wig out
3. This is a bonus, but I originally visualized that the markers would
   animate in an incremented order rather than all at the same time.
   Could be random or it could be defined. I think it would make the
   animation look more fluid. I figure that this would call for a loop
   but like I mentioned earlier I only know enough to be dangerous.

Here is the link to the page: http://204.12.117.109/~sandbox/map/

Here is the jquery Code I'm using:

```
$(function() {
        $('.city').mouseenter(function(){

            var relid = $(this).attr('rel');

            $("#communities div[id!=" + relid + "].pin").animate({
                opacity: 0,
                top: '-=40',
                }, 500);
        });
        $('.city').mouseleave(function(){

            var relid = $(this).attr('rel');

            $("#communities div[id!=" + relid + "].pin").animate({
                opacity: 1,
                top: '+=40',
                }, 500, 'easeOutBounce');
        });
    });
```

Here's the CSS I'm using:

```
#communities { background: url(images/bgCommunities.gif) scroll bottom right no-repeat; position: relative; }
    #communities .lists { width: 340px !important; }
    #cities li { width: 160px !important; margin: 0px 2px !important; padding: 4px 0 4px 4px; }
    #cities li:hover { background-color: rgb(240,240,240); }
        #boyle, #long, #santa, #rich, #fres, #sac, #city, #sLA, #coach, #kern, #oak, #merc, #sal, #del { position: absolute; width: 8px; height: 12px; background: url(images/pin.png) 0 0 no-repeat; }
        #boyle { top: 230px; right: 95px; }
        #long { top: 241px; right: 92px; }
        #santa { top: 236px; right: 84px; }
        #rich { top: 139px; right: 165px; }
        #fres { top: 173px; right: 121px; }
        #sac { top: 133px; right: 147px; }
        #city { top: 258px; right: 78px; }
        #sLA { top: 235px; right: 90px; }
        #coach { top: 239px; right: 62px; }
        #kern { top: 206px; right: 105px; }
        #oak { top: 148px; right: 162px; }
        #merc { top: 161px; right: 136px; }
        #sal { top: 171px; right: 155px; }
        #del { top: 71px; right: 185px; }
```

Here's the HTML I'm using:

```
<div id="communities">
<div class="lists">
    <ul id="cities">
        <li class="city" rel="boyle"><a href="#">Boyle Heights</a></li>
        <li class="city" rel="long"><a href="#">Long Beach</a></li>
        <li class="city" rel="santa"><a href="#">Central Santa Ana</a></li>
        <li class="city" rel="rich"><a href="#">Richmond</a></li>
        <li class="city" rel="fres"><a href="#">Central/SE/SW Fresno</a></li>
        <li class="city" rel="sac"><a href="#">Sacramento</a></li>
        <li class="city" rel="city"><a href="#">City Heights</a></li>
        <li class="city" rel="sLA"><a href="#">South Los Angeles</a></li>
        <li class="city" rel="coach"><a href="#" >Coachella Valley</a></li>
        <li class="city" rel="kern"><a href="#">South Kern</a></li>
        <li class="city" rel="oak"><a href="#">East Oakland</a></li>
        <li class="city" rel="merc"><a href="#">SW Merced/East Merced</a></li>
        <li class="city" rel="sal"><a href="#">East Salinas (Alisal)</a></li>
        <li class="city" rel="del"><a href="#">Del Norte County</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="pin" id="boyle"></div>
<div class="pin" id="long"></div>
<div class="pin" id="santa"></div>
<div class="pin" id="rich"></div>
<div class="pin" id="fres"></div>
<div class="pin" id="sac"></div>
<div class="pin" id="city"></div>
<div class="pin" id="sLA"></div>
<div class="pin" id="coach"></div>
<div class="pin" id="kern"></div>
<div class="pin" id="oak"></div>
<div class="pin" id="merc"></div>
<div class="pin" id="sal"></div>
<div class="pin" id="del"></div>
```

Comment: Please rename your title 'How do I fix my buggy code?' so that it's easier for others to understand your question. Your title is too general now. Also try making your CSS and HTML simpler so that it's easier to go through.

Comment: Hey Tuva, I'm sorry I don't really know how I can make the CSS and HTML simpler without breaking the functionality. I don't know if you saw my link or not but if you haven't maybe seeing the code in action will clear the question up: [link](http://204.12.117.109/~sandbox/map/)

Answer (score 1):

Got it (02:31est)! (now working on the random version ... I like a challenge!):

EDIT (see http://zequinha-bsb.int-domains.com/map/cities.html)

Got it 2 @ 3:29am est (am I being paid by the hour ... or at all?) 
Random version is on the bottom part with it's respective link.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var firstEntry = true;
    var lastOn = '';

    function showAllPins() {
        if ($('#communities').hasClass('theMouseIsOff')) {
            $("#communities div[id!=''].pin").animate({
                opacity: 1,
                top: '+=40',
            }, 500, 'easeOutBounce');
            firstEntry = true;
            $('#communities').removeClass('theMouseIsOff');
        }
    }
    function showPin(relid){
        lastOn = relid;
        if ($('#communities').hasClass('theMouseIsOff')) $('#communities').removeClass('theMouseIsOff');
        if (firstEntry == true) {
            $("#communities div[id!=" + relid + "].pin").animate({
                opacity: 0,
                top: '-=40',
            }, 500);
            firstEntry = false;
        } else {
            $("#communities div[id=" + relid + "].pin").animate({
                opacity: 1,
                top: '+=40',
            }, 500, 'easeOutBounce');
        }
    }
    function removeLastPin() {
        $('#communities').addClass('theMouseIsOff');
        $("#communities div[id=" + lastOn + "].pin").animate({
            opacity: 0,
            top: '-=40',
        }, 500);
        setTimeout('showAllPins()',5000);
    }

    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('.city').mouseenter( function () {
            relid = $(this).attr('rel');
            showPin(relid);
        }).mouseleave( function () { removeLastPin() });
    });

</script>
```

The random version:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var firstEntry = true;
    var lastOn = '';

    function showAllPins() {
        if ($('#communities').hasClass('theMouseIsOff')) {
            var citiesArr = [];
            $('.pin').each( function () { 
                citiesArr.push(this.id);
                $('#'+this.id).hide();
            });
            var stillHidden = citiesArr.length;
            while (stillHidden > 0) {
                var a = Math.floor(Math.random()*citiesArr.length);
                if ($('#'+citiesArr[a]).is(':hidden')) {
                    $('#'+citiesArr[a]).show().delay(Math.floor(Math.random()*900)).animate({
                        opacity: 1,
                        top: '+=40',
                    }, Math.floor(Math.random()*900), 'easeOutBounce');
                    stillHidden--;
                }
            }
            firstEntry = true;
            $('#communities').removeClass('theMouseIsOff');
        }
    }
    function showPin(relid){
        lastOn = relid;
        if ($('#communities').hasClass('theMouseIsOff')) $('#communities').removeClass('theMouseIsOff');
        if (firstEntry == true) {
            $("#communities div[id!=" + relid + "].pin").animate({
                opacity: 0,
                top: '-=40',
            }, 500);
            firstEntry = false;
        } else {
            $("#communities div[id=" + relid + "].pin").animate({
                opacity: 1,
                top: '+=40',
            }, 500, 'easeOutBounce');
        }
    }
    function removeLastPin() {
        $('#communities').addClass('theMouseIsOff');
        $("#communities div[id=" + lastOn + "].pin").animate({
            opacity: 0,
            top: '-=40',
        }, 500);
        setTimeout('showAllPins()',2000);
    }

    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('.city').mouseenter( function () {
            relid = $(this).attr('rel');
            showPin(relid);
        }).mouseleave( function () { removeLastPin() });
    });

</script>
```

EDIT (removed relid as parameter in removeLastPin)

You can check it here: http://zequinha-bsb.int-domains.com/map/randomCities.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply zeq, but it looks like this works only on the first rollover.  After that, it just keeps pushing the markers down the page.

Comment: I am trying to copy your site over so I can make the final version. I could not download the sprites as the ../images/... is not accessible from within the sandbox. I do have an error already found: the "" on show all should be id==''; not id=="" (single quotes instead of double quotes).

Comment: here I've loaded your code into jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/luniablue/e4LWU/15/

Comment: That looks awesome. Thank you very much for helping me out with this!

Comment: Please vote the answer up and choose it as your accepted answer. Thank you in advance. BTW: Great project!

Comment: I like to think that every time I help someone, I get to learn a bit more. Of course not all projects are of my interest. Someone else states in his profile that S.O. is adictive. I am starting to believe that to be very true.

Answer (score 0):

This example should clear things up for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/wJnr5/3

What you need to do is bind an event to the container that holds the cities. When the mouse leaves this container is when you want to reshow all the cities. I also used a better jQuery selector to get everything except for the current city.

```
$('.city').bind('mouseenter', 
    function() {
        //fade out everyone but me
        $('.city').not($(this)).each( function() {                            
            $(this).stop().delay(Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)).animate({ opacity: 0 });
        });
        //fade me in
        $(this).stop().animate({ opacity: 1 });
    }
);

$('#container').bind('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.city').stop().animate({ opacity: 1 });    
});
```

Comment: Even better now. Cities are randomly faded in according to specification 3.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I'll make sure to archive this for future uses, but unfortunately it's not the text that I'm animating.  The text links are targeting marker icons absolutely positioned over a map. Can the bind solution work when targeting multiple elements outside of the bound element? See my link for functionality:  [link]http://204.12.117.109/~sandbox/map/

Comment: The code will work the exact same way in the end. Just change the selector expressions to target your markers instead of your cities. So for example change `.city` to `.marker`. You won't be able to use the $(this), but just pick the one you want like you did in your old code.

Comment: if you want to discuss more - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/5038/talk-time?tab=general